# How can I erase image url in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently making a function to upload and delete images in react. If I upload the image through the model window, I can see the image on the screen, and if I press the delete button, I want to remove the image. The problem is that I can upload the image well, but I can't delete the image. I want to delete the image by erasing the url value of the image, but even if I try to delete it, the url value of the image continues to be included. It seems that the url of the image is constantly being recalled from which part, so where should I modify it to remove the url of the image? I'd appreciate it if you let me know, thanks!

**MakeModal.jsx:***

This is the component of the model window, and if I register the image here, the url of the image is saved in `preview`. And it is passed to parent component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

function MakeModal({passUrl}) {

  //upload image

  const fileInput = React.useRef(null);
  
  const [isfile,setIsfile] = useState("");
  
  const handleButtonClick = e => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setIsfile(e.target.files[0]);
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
  }; 

  //take image url
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState('');

  passUrl(preview)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isfile) {
      const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(isfile); 
        setPreview(objectUrl);
      }
      return () => URL.revokeObjectURL(isfile);      
    }, [isfile]);

  return (
    <Modal>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    {/* upload image */}
                  <input 
                    type="file" 
                    style={{display:'none'}}
                    ref={fileInput}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    multiple={true}/>
                    <button 
                      onClick={handleButtonClick}
                      className='box9_2_3_3_2'>
                      choose image
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default MakeModal;
```

**Profile.jsx:**

I want to show and delete the image in this component. I received url value using `passUrl` function from child component. And when I press the delete button, I made a function to erase the value of url, but the value is not erased and the value continues to be filled. Or maybe the value is erased and then refilled. How can I empty url?

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import MakeModal from '../components/MakeModal';

function Profile() {

  //receive image from child
  const [imgUrl,setImgUrl] = useState("");
  const passUrl = (url) => {
    setImgUrl(url)
  }

  //delete image
  const noImg = (e) => {
    setImgUrl("")
  }

  //check
  console.log("imgUrl",imgUrl)

  return (
    <>
      <ProfileWrap>    
        <div >
          <section>
            <main>
              <div>
                <header>
                  <section>
                    <div>
                      <span>
                        <div onClick={noImg}>
                          delete
                        </div>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </section>
                </header>
                <div>
                  <article>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <img 
                          src={imgUrl}
                          alt='defaultprofile'
                          className='IMgdiv'/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                </div>
              </div>
            </main>
          </section>
        </div>
      </ProfileWrap>
      <MakeModal passUrl={passUrl}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the image url in the state of the component and just setImageUrl(null)

in rendered component:

```
imageUrl ?? <image module here> //displays image if there's a url in state
```

you might need to make some changes but I think you get the idea

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).